# How do I find my Geometry Dash song files on PC through Steam file browsing?

Tags: steam, geometry-dash

I can't find the song file location. I tried looking through `Steam>GeometryDash>Propreties>Browselocalfiles`. I want to replace my Songs with non-Newgrounds songs, but I can't find the song locations! I've tried `%appdata%`, but Geometry Dash doesn't show up in there because of steam file browsing. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

go to %localappdata%\GeometryDash

Heres how